# Rails 4 ajax load partial into view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, partial

there is a way to put an input dynamically from button?
Example:

this is the form:

```
    <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
```

.
...

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :productlist %><br>
    <%= f.select :productlist, @products, :prompt => 'Select one!' %>
    <%= link_to 'Add More', '#', id: 'products-link' %>
  </div>
  <div id="newproduct">
    <p>load here the new input on Add more link</p>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

so i thinked up to ajax and a way to load a partial input into the form, but im not understanding the correct way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more clear of what you're trying to achieve with adding the partial via ajax.

Comment: the same select tag into form, exactly this:
    <%= f.select :productlist, @products, :prompt => 'Select one!' %>

Comment: You can try [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) templating. Write common code inside a **.ejs** file and render it when required

Comment: thanks but i'm finding an ajax way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript file add:

```
  $("a#products-link").click(function(){
    $.get('/partials/products_form', function(data){
      $("div#newproduct").append(data);
    }, 'html');
  });
```

Essentially what is happening is that you are going to send a `get` request via ajax to a form in `/partials/products_form` or wherever you choose to keep your form partial. And then this html will be appended to whatever div/identifier you choose in this case `div#newproduct`.

Comment: Thanks for reply:
The js seems not wotk maybe im wrong 

This is the controller:
http://pastebin.com/7khy5HR0
The Form:
http://pastebin.com/Td2zmVAZ
PArtial:
http://pastebin.com/KX1CrwQv
And the js:
http://pastebin.com/MuvJHSDP

Comment: Ok, your javascript file should not be `create.js.erb`. It is just a regular javascript file in your assets folder, like `products.js`. Also the first parameter inside your `$.get()` function is a url, in my case I am sending a get request to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/partials/products_form`. You want to send a get request to one of your actions in your controller. You can check the paths of all your actions by going to your command prompt or terminal and typing `rake routes` in the directory of your application.

Comment: You're going to have to make a new action in your products controller that will be listening for this get request.